# Testing Java class using JUnit

Tags: java, junit

```
public void printSummaryForPatient(String name){
    Patient p = findPatient(name);
    p.printPatientSummary();
    p.computeBMI();
}
```

My method to test:

```
@Test
public void testPrintSummaryForPatient() {

    Patient patient_adult=new Patient("Ted",24,1.90,70.0,"Leicester");
    //Patient Patient_child=new Patient("Kate",4,1.90,70.0,"Leicester");
   // Patient Patient_elderly=new Patient("Bill",124,1.90,70.0,"Leicester");


    surgery_N.findPatient("Ted");   
    patient_adult.printPatientSummary();
    assertEquals("Ted", patient_adult.getName());
    assertEquals("-----------PATIENT SUMMARY: ---------"+"\n"+"NAME: "+patient_adult.name+"\n"+"Age: "+patient_adult.getAge()+"\n"+"Address: "+patient_adult.getAddress()+"\n"+"Height: "+patient_adult.getHeight()+"\n"+"Weight: "+patient_adult.getWeight()+"\n"+"------------------------------"+separator,ans.toString());
    patient_adult.computeBMI();
    assertEquals(19.390581717451525, patient_adult.computeBMI(), 0.0);


}`
```

The problem is that the way I use  to test doesn't cover the original file at all. Hope  I can get some help from you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign a different writer to System.out (assuming that's where your output goes) and inspect what gets written there. In general, you probably want to make the writer a parameter of printSummary or inject it into the class somehow.

Comment: I wouldn't even inject it - I'd just "separate the concerns" - make one method to generate the report and return it as a String, have another method just call it and print it out.  Then you can actually test your report generator method since it's returning something.

Comment: That would work as well. But assuming we are talking about a web service doing this frequently, buffering Strings in memory is not the nicest thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to do this:

```
@Test
public void testPrintSummaryForPatient() {
  Patient patient_adult=new Patient("Ted",24,1.90,70.0,"Leicester");
  surgery_N.printSummaryForPatient("Ted");
}
```

But can't do any asserts, because the Patient is not returned.

Do you want to return the patient?:

```
public Patient printSummaryForPatient(String name){
    Patient p = findPatient(name);
    p.printPatientSummary();
    p.computeBMI();
    return p;
}
```

After that you could use your assertions. It seems more like a conceptual problem of how you organize your methods.

You have methods in printSummaryForPatient, that don't seem to do anything. Their return value is not returned or saved.